# [Youtube Rate API getting 403 Error in ios app]

Tags: ios, api, youtube, rate

I refer this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate

I have registered the credential client key for google API 
, now I need give like or dislike for youtube video by using the Google YouTube rate API.  I am getting a 403 error, even though I have supplied an accesstoken in the header. I have supplied an accesstoken in parameter also, as well as id, rate key.

I expect to get 204 code but I am getting 403

NSString *accesstoken = user.authentication.accessToken;
 NSString * authSting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",accesstoken];
 i add accesstoken like below and also added in parameter also
Bearer ya29.GlvzBnHpl4DM_JnQ6Xqrc-fb1gTviZuZbfx7_W_lGRu34XWaLa3KKNksKd2lS8iyprez5PscNumQbz3ivH5UsHPBcDnE90k6cWNmHfEDyyN8LFNL04j4YO_AoCmq

i adding my parameter below 
{
    "access_token" = "ya29.GlvzBnHpl4DM_JnQ6Xqrc-fb1gTviZuZbfx7_W_lGRu34XWaLa3KKNksKd2lS8iyprez5PscNumQbz3ivH5UsHPBcDnE90k6cWNmHfEDyyN8LFNL04j4YO_AoCmq";
    id = "Iq_cwCf9nmQ";
    rating = like;
}
 NSString *baseURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/rate"];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Authorization": authSting,
                                            @"Content-Type":@"application/json"};

Like this i added my code but still i got 403 error. i checked in youtube channel that video enabled ratings its possible like dislike count, but in google youtube rating api getting 403. pls help me.

Comment: Have you successfully authenticated as a user in order to obtain the access token?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 403 can be occure

> The video that you are trying to rate cannot be rated. The request might not be properly authorized.

or

> The owner of the video that you are trying to rate has disabled ratings for that video.

you are trapped in any of the situation, please check if your auth key is properly set in header